# What does this LC circuit do

Tags: filter

[image]

Can someone explain what does it circuit do? Is it some kind of filter? Thanks.

Comment: All real circuits have some resistance. At resonance the series LC has an impedance that approaches zero, the parallel LC tends to infinity.

Comment: Each component shifts the phase from Vi. The +&- shifts balance at one frequency and appear in phase at Vo. Leaving other frequencies out of phase.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework question? If so, here are some hints to get you going:

Divide the circuit into three branches at the top-center node. The left and right branches each comprise a series combination of L and C. The bottom branch comprises a parallel combination of L and C.

What do you know about the impedance characteristics of series L-C circuits and parallel L-C circuits? What does that imply about the transfer characteristics of the circuit as a whole, at resonance, and off-resonance?